# CassandraDaemon.java:195 - Exception in thread Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:10,5,main]

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, centos, jna

I am trying to install cassandra v3.0.2 on Centos 7. I followed the instructions exactly and I am getting this below error. Just to reiterate I did yum install jna and the version is at 4.0.0 in the /usr/share/java and as well as cassandra lib directory

Below is the Stacktrace

```
*ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:9] 2016-01-25 20:40:05,801 CassandraDaemon.java:195 - Exception in thread Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:9,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.memory.MemoryUtil.allocate(MemoryUtil.java:95) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.(Memory.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.(SafeMemory.java:32) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$Writer.(CompressionMetadata.java:316) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$Writer.open(CompressionMetadata.java:330) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:76) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:163) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.(BigTableWriter.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigFormat$WriterFactory.open(BigFormat.java:93) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create(SSTableWriter.java:96) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.create(SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.java:114) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.createSSTableMultiWriter(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:514) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.createSSTableMultiWriter(CompactionStrategyManager.java:506) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createSSTableMultiWriter(ColumnFamilyStore.java:472) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:432) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:366) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runMayThrow(Memtable.java:352) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:299) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1037) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_66]*
```

Comment: using openjdk or oracle jdk?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink : Using oracle jdk 1.8

Answer (score 1):

This was a permission issue with /tmp.Apparently a chmod of 777 on the /tmp did not work. I came to know this when I ran a sample program using the jna.jar and it clearly printed out the error. Apparently we use centos -7  hardened image which is different from the normal centos-7 and hence my issues.

To solve the issue I moved the cassandra temp/output directory
/home/cassandra.

But it would be nice if cassandra logs printed out that it was permission issue with /tmp

Answer (score 0):

Run Cassandra service as root user . issue will be resolved

Comment: Running services as `root` is a very dangerous solution, especially when they do not need `root` permissions (e.g., specific system calls, maintenance tasks) at all.